# create a dictionary of class names by an attribute of each class

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I have a set of classes that have as one of their attributes a url.  I would like to build a dictionary of those classes, keyed by that url.  Here is the code I have come up with:

```
class pagesByUrl(dict):
    "a cross reference of pages by url rather than object name"
    def __init__(self):
        pages={}
        for page in dir(xxxPages):
            try:
                pgAttr=getattr(xxxPages, page)
                pg=pgAttr('dummybrowser')
                pages[pg.url] = page
            except (KeyError, TypeError, AttributeError):
                pass
        print pages #At this point, the dictionary is good.
        self=pages
        print self #Also here, still just what I want.




pg=pagesByUrl()
print "pg is:", pg #But here, pg is an empty dictionary.
```

What can I do to have this class instantiate as the dictionary that I want?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a problem or not, but you never call `dict.__init__(self)`

Comment: I would also recommend being consistend with whitespace around `=`.  In one place you have:  `pages[pg.url] = page` and in others `pg=pgAttr('dummybrowser')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class pagesByUrl(dict):
    "a cross reference of pages by url rather than object name"
    def __init__(self):
        dict.__init__(self) #!
        pages={}
        for page in dir(xxxPages):
            try:
                pgAttr=getattr(xxxPages, page)
                pg=pgAttr('dummybrowser')
                pages[pg.url] = page
            except (KeyError, TypeError, AttributeError):
                pass

       self.update(pages)
       #Alternatively, forgo the previous `dict.__init__(self)` and the 
       #previous line and do:
       #dict.__init__(self,pages)
```

If you do `self = pages`, you're simply replacing the local name `self` in the `__init__` function with the `pages` dictionary.  You're not actually mutating the dictionary which was `self`.

Of course, at this point, there's no need to have the `pages` dict at all -- We can just use `self`:

```
class pagesByUrl(dict):
    "a cross reference of pages by url rather than object name"
    def __init__(self):
        dict.__init__(self)
        for page in dir(xxxPages):
            try:
                pgAttr=getattr(xxxPages, page)
                pg=pgAttr('dummybrowser')
                self[pg.url] = page
            except (KeyError, TypeError, AttributeError):
                pass
```

Comment: Ah, that is much cleaner. Let me give it a try.

Comment: Perfect.  New tool to add to my arsenal.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `__new__()` method for instance creation, if you want to have pure "type dict"

```
class dictA(dict):
    def __new__(self):
        self._pages={"one":1, "two":2}
        return self._pages

class pagesByUrl(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        _pages = {"one":1, "two":2}
        dict.__init__(self)
        self.update(_pages)

d = {"one":1, "two":2}
print type(d)
print d

d = dictA()
print type(d)
print d

d = pagesByUrl()
print type(d)
print d
```

Output:

```
<type 'dict'>
{'two': 2, 'one': 1}
<type 'dict'>
{'two': 2, 'one': 1}
<class '__main__.pagesByUrl'>
{'two': 2, 'one': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Not really what I need for this application.